# How to access Rebus from other languages?

Tags: rebus

How to integrate other languages than those from .net world? For example to access messages from the bus in Java or C++? Do I have to listen to the queue in the backend instead? Is there a common Api provided by Rebus?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While Rebus may market itself as a "service bus"(*), it is actually more a kind of a "driver" with a common abstraction that enables .NET programmers to use various queues and persistence technologies without worrying too much about the specifics.

As such, Rebus cannot really be connected to, much as you would not be able to connect to, say, the `NpgsqlConnection` or the `SqlConnection` you would use to communicate with your Postgres or SQL Server database.

What you *could* do, was to interface with Rebus at the transport and/or persistence level, e.g. by using the same wire-level format when exchanging messages.

This would require that the chosen transport (MSMQ, RabbitMQ, SQL Server, etc.) can be interfaced with from the desired platform, and then you would need to be able to supply the correct headers for Rebus to accept the message as valid.

There is no official Rebus implementation for any other platforms besides .NET (.NET 4.5 + .NET Standard 1.3).

To my knowledge, no one has attempted to actually build a Rebus-compatible messaging library on any other platform.

---

(*) I actually usually use the word "messaging library" to describe it, because I think it carries way less confusion and semantic overload with it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. I think we need to know a minimal message format that an application for example PHP can compose and send directly to an endpoint queue. That would make life easy in certain cases.